# xCode 6 - View console from application running in emulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6, nslog

I have my iPhone emulator opened not from xCode environment, and I have my application installed on it. In my application I use NSLog to print messages to console.

How can I open a console view for the emulator so I can see the messages printed by the application?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.

iOS Simluator > Debug Menu > Open System Log.

or Press 'Command + /'

Voila! You would be able to see all your logs now.

Comment: I see messages in there but not my NSLog messages

Comment: check the screenshot which I just took : http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2014-10-19_at_10.05.15_PM.png

Comment: When I start the console app using cmd + / at the title of the app window I see system.log - is it supposed to be that or something else?

Comment: @developer82 Yes. System log it is.